# Passing variables to views in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In CodeIgniter you can pass a data array to views as in:

```
$this->load->view("view_name", array("key" => "value"));
```

and then access the variable in the view simply as $variable_name.

I'm trying to achieve the same thing in Laravel without necessarily storing the data in the session. The answers that I've seen suggest doing something like:

```
return view("view_name")->with("variable_name", $variable_value);
```

But doesn't that store it in the session? I'm looking to simply pass the variables directly to the view so as to avoid cluttering up the session with things that I'm passing to various views from controller methods.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: what you did is correct, and it's not saving in session. this passing variable to view https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views , and this for session https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#storing-data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compact()` to pass an array of the variables in your controller to your view. The `compact()` function will create an array from the variable names passed into it.

Controller class

```php
public function showDashboard() 
{ 
    $total_sales = Sale::sum('price'); 
    $average_sales = Sale::avg('price'); 
 
    return view('dashboard.show',compact('total_sales','average_sales'));
}
```

blade file

```html
    <p> 
        Total sales made is {{$total_sales}} at average of {{$average_sales}} 
    </p>
```